# get selected values from multiple dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the application I am making, I have several dropdown lists (more than 10). I having trouble getting the results of each dropdown list on a button click. I need an iterative way to get the options selected by the user from each dropdown.

I am able to get the values from one dropdown using the following:

```
let drops = [];
$(document).delegate("select", "change", function() {
    var values = $('#drop1').val(); // type of array
    drops = values;
});
console.log(drops);
```

But I need an iterative way to get the selected values from all dropdowns. Here is my attempt:

```
$('#btner').click(function() {
    var values;
    $('#container > .d-flex > select').each(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('id'); //gets id of each dropdown
        $(document).delegate("select", "change", function() {
            values = $('#' + id).val(); // type of array
        });
        console.log(values);
    });

})
```

Here is the general structure of my code.

```js
new TomSelect('#drop1', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});

new TomSelect('#drop2', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});


new TomSelect('#drop3', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop1" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
        <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
        <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop2" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item4">Item4</option>
        <option value="Item5">Item5</option>
        <option value="Item6">Item6</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <br><br>
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop3" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item7">Item7</option>
        <option value="Item8">Item8</option>
        <option value="Item9">Item9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <br> <br>
  <button id="btner" type="button" class="btn"> Sumbit </button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that delegate is deprecated in favor of using `on()` which it will already use under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()`.

I'm not sure what format you want them in so the following returns a multidimensional array.

It would be an easy modification to return an object that includes the id and values for each

```js
$('#btner').on('click', function(e) {
  const selVals = $('.d-flex select').map((i, el) => [$(el).val()]).get();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(selVals))
});



const opts = {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
}

new TomSelect('#drop1', opts);
new TomSelect('#drop2', opts);
new TomSelect('#drop3', opts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
    <select id="drop1" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
      <option value="Item2" selected>Item2</option>
      <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
    <select id="drop2" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Item4">Item4</option>
      <option value="Item5" selected>Item5</option>
      <option value="Item6" selected>Item6</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <br><br>
  <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
    <select id="drop3" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Item7">Item7</option>
      <option value="Item8" selected>Item8</option>
      <option value="Item9">Item9</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<br> <br>
<button id="btner" type="button" class="btn"> Sumbit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to get all dropdown selected values

```js
$('#btner').click(function() {
    var values = [];    
    values.push($("#drop1 :selected").map((_, e) => e.value).get());
    values.push($("#drop2 :selected").map((_, e) => e.value).get());
    values.push($("#drop3 :selected").map((_, e) => e.value).get());  
    console.log(values)
})




new TomSelect('#drop1', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});

new TomSelect('#drop2', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});


new TomSelect('#drop3', {
  sortField: 'text',
  hideSelected: false,
  duplicates: true,
  plugins: ['input_autogrow'],
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@1.7.5/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop1" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
        <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
        <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop2" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item4">Item4</option>
        <option value="Item5">Item5</option>
        <option value="Item6">Item6</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <br><br>
    <div class="d-flex" id="menuItems" style="width: 58%;">
      <select id="drop3" style="width: 100%;" multiple data-mdb-option-height="44">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Item7">Item7</option>
        <option value="Item8">Item8</option>
        <option value="Item9">Item9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <br> <br>
  <button id="btner" type="button" class="btn"> Sumbit </button>
 
</body>
</html>
```